When debugging React performance, how should I interpret a node in the Chrome inspect tab flashing purple?
I'm working on a react app and trying to debug some extra redraws. Looking at the Chrome inspect tab, the document body appears to be flashing purple on several of the redraws.
When an element flashes purple, how should that be interpreted? Is it a full redraw of the element, or do those flashes represent mutations or DOM changes such as adding children to the tree?
